# Where is $\sqrt{z+1}$ analytic and continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

> I am trying to determine where $$f(z)=\sqrt{z+1}$$ is analytic, where the square root is the principal branch.

I know that $\sqrt{w}$ is analytic for $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. So, I think $f(z)$ is not analytic when $\Re(z)\leq-1$. Is this correct?

As for continuity, I would like to determine if $f(z)$ is continuous at $\Re(z)=-1$ by taking the limit from above and below. But I am unsure of how to do this.
 Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $z<-1$ is $z$ is a complex number

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that. I have fixed this.

Comment: Bell, if you wanted to say that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,-1]$, that's definitely not the same as $\operatorname{Re}z\leq 1$. I would return to what you wrote originally. As Tony said, it doesn't make sense to write $z\leq -1$ if $z$ is complex number, so one should automatically assume that $z$ is real seeing that.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. If $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$\ $(-\infty,-1]$, is this not the same as saying $f$ is not analytic for $x=\Re(z)\leq -1$?

Comment: Is $z = -2+3i$ in both sets or just one of them?

Comment: I do not see what you're getting at it. The function $h(z)=-2+3i$ is entire. Are you referring to my previous comment?

Comment: In short, $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,-1]\neq \{z\in\mathbb C\mid \operatorname{Re} z > -1\}$.

Comment: Agreed. The LHS simply excludes the branch from $(-\infty,-1)$. What made you think I thought otherwise?

Comment: At first you wrote $z\leq -1$ which I interpreted as $(-\infty,-1]$, but then you changed it to $\operatorname{Re}z\leq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ there is an continuous determination of the argument defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus e^{i\theta}\mathbb{R_-}$. (The formula is $\operatorname{Arg}(z)= 2\operatorname{Arctan}(\frac{\operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\theta}z)}{|z|+\operatorname{Re}(e^{-i\theta}z)})+\theta$). So there is an continuous log on the same open given by $\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, and which is then analytic. You can then define your function with the formula $f(z)=\exp(\log(z+1)/2)$ which is analytic on $\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Arg(z+1)}\neq \theta\}$. If $\theta\neq 0$, your function is continuous at $-1$.

Comment: If you choose the principal branch of the log, then you will have $f(z)$ continuous at -1 because the log will tend to $-\infty$.